# Cursor with a dynamic where clause

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I've got a very large sql statement that I'd like to replicate across lots of procedures. In each procedure I have different requirements for the where statement (like "where employee.is_fired = 'Y'" or "where employee.salary > 50000") and I'd like to reuse the cursor without having to rewrite or complicate its use. Is there someway to use a cursor or similar structure with a dynamic where statement?

Comment: Does it need to be dynamic SQL?  It sounds like you're describing a use case for a view.  Maybe a pipelined table function if the predicates you want to add aren't very selective or the "large SQL statement" is relatively inexpensive to run.

Comment: you may be declare static part of your sql statement in package specification such as "sql select clause and from clause" etc. and use this variable in building you sql query in any other package as they will be available as global variable. attach your dynamic where clause to this static and form sql.